# With this Class component I geocoded a value but now im unable to set the value as a state in the same component, How can I save the geocoded value?

Tags: reactjs, components, geocode

In this component I ask the user for their address information in order to determine whether or not they are in the Delivery radius for a restaurant, once they submit their address I send a axiom get request (Which I am completely new to) and then I get a response with the geocoded data I need. I now need to move this data but I am unsure how to.

Essentially I wish to save the response from this geocode request, if there are different ways I am 10000000% open to learn. Thank you for your time.

```js
class GoogleGeocode extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      Address: '',
      Zipcode: '',
      City: '',
      Location: 'placeholder',
    };

    this.geocode = this.geocode.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
  }
  geocode() {
    axios
      .get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
          address: this.state.Address,
          key: API_KEY,
        },
      })
      .then(function (response) {
        // Response data i want returned as a state
        console.log(response.data.results[0].geometry.location);
        // Example
        // this.setState({Location : response.data.results[0].geometry.location })
      })

      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
  }
  handleInputChange(e) {
    const target = e.target;
    const value = target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value,
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Address"
          value={this.state.Address}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
          name="Address"
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="Zipcode"
          name="Zipcode"
          value={this.state.Zipcode}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="City"
          name="City"
          value={this.state.City}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <button onClick={this.geocode}>Verify Address</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why this is right, but I changed the function to an arrow function and it worked! still, if anyone could answer i'd appreciate it. <3

```js
.then((response) => {
        this.props.SetLocation(response.data.results[0].geometry.location);
        this.props.CheckLocation();
      })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```